# removing element of an array that with a match of certain element

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb collection.

> { user_id: 1,
>     items : [ { _id: 1 }, { _id: 2}, {_id:3} ] }

I want to remove the items of the array having specific id. Can anybody explain what is wrong with the above query.

```
db.col.findOneAndUpdate({user_id:1},{$pull:{items:{$elemMatch:{_id:2}}}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents) takes an expression as a parameter so you don't have to use `$elemMatch` (doesn't work in this case). Try:

```
db.col.update({user_id:1},{$pull:{items:{_id:2}}})
```

So expression in this case means that MongoDB will remove the document having `_id` set to `2` but that document can have other properties as well.